# Angulad ng-time-ago returns same value

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, momentjs, angular-moment

Even I added `angularMoment` module to my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myreddit', ['ionic', 'angularMoment']);
```

I also imported it from `index.html`

```
<script src="lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="lib/moment/locale/en-gb.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

I want to show directive time by passing this: `{{story.created_utc}}` to a`m-time-ago`, but the problem is that it doesn't return different value even if passed values are different.

Passed values:

[image: Passed value 1]

[image: Passed value 2]

Returned values :

[image: Return 1]

[image: Return 2]

Comment: could you please provide the complete code or plunkr link, which will help me find the root cause

Comment: @Pramod_Para Which file you need exactly ?

Comment: Your custom directive code and the template code which is rendering your times(if it's not part of the directive and stored is a separate file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use [`amFromUnix`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amfromunix-filter) flter that:

> Converts a unix-timestamp (seconds since 1/1/1970) into a moment object.

Here a working sample:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.story = {};
  $scope.story.created_utc = 1490029481;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <span am-time-ago="story.created_utc | amFromUnix"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

moment.js can use either seconds or milliseconds in a Date constructor, but milliseconds is the default. You're passing seconds.
So, you can either multiply by 1000, or use moment.unix(timestamp) instead of moment(timestamp)

In Angular, that would be something like:

```
<span am-time-ago="message.unixTime | amFromUnix">
```